# how to do if-else in kotlin flow and function programming

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

How can I do this spilt on `events` in one step, how if-else is done in functional programming / call chains?

```kotlin
events.filter {
    it.isUniqueEvent
}.collectLatest {
    handleEvent(it)
    sendAnalyticsEvent(it)
}

events.filterNot {
    it.isUniqueEvent
}.collect {
    handleEvent(it)
    sendAnalyticsEvent(it)
}
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to even try to do this in another way. You need to handle both cases much differently, so I think they should be implemented separately. If you are concerned you need to create two source flows, then you can create an intermediate shared flow. But `events` flow sounds like a shared flow already.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` + `filterNot` to split the flows + handle the events in their own way. NOTE: do not `collect()` YET.

Then you can use [merge](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/merge.html) to combine both flows into one.

In the end you use `collect` on the resulting flow.

```
// handles unique events
val unique = events.filter { it.isUniqueEvent}
    .onEach { handleEvent(it) }

// handles not unique events
val notUnique = events.filterNot { it.isUniqueEvent}
    .onEach { handleEvent(it) }

val all = merge(unique, noUnique)

...

all.launchIn(scope)
```

Note: I replaced `collectLates` with `onEach` for the unique flow which is not the same behavior. You can implement the same behavior using `transformLatest`. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2214